# English Syntax Tree: is the "to do X" a CP?

Tags: syntax-trees

I have a sentence that says "He was required **to** work in the kitchen" (actually, another example, doesn't really matter, the question is in principle): what is the function of "to" here? Is it a complementiser?

Extra question: does the second VP (work) require an IP?

e.g. in this sentence:

[image: syntax tree with "to do X"]

As for tree-formation, I am basically using X-bar but I am not really that verse that I can say I am without fault here...

Comment: Yes, _to_ is part of the _for ... to_ infinitive complementizer. As for the extra IP, I wouldn't put it in, but I go to a different church and don't have to follow other dogmas. Consult your confessor for what's **really** required, and why.